# Debug WCF service in IIS with object as input

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, wcftestclient

I want to debug a WCF service locally in Visual Studio. The called function looks like this:

```
public void PerformAction(Directory[] dirs) {
    ....
}
```

Directory is a class with some properties. In the WCF test client I want to test the function but how can I set the input values for the Directory array?

Comment: Can you put the URL/endpoint that the host application is listening on into a browser or some other client and make a error free connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the default WCF template as an example, I made the following definition.

```
[OperationContract]
        //[WebGet(RequestFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json,ResponseFormat =WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData(CompositeType[] value);

        public string GetData(CompositeType[] value)
        {
            return string.Format("You entered: {0},{1}", value[0].StringValue,value[1].StringValue);
        }
```

First enter the length of the array, then select the array type, and finally enter the values of the individual elements one by one.
[image]
Wish it is useful to you, feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I only have to set the length to !=0 :)